# tiger-vnc server will not restart

Tags: tightvnc

I've setup a tiger-vnc server on a centos 7 host in my home lab and recently had a power outage. I tried connecting to the vnc server as usual and got a "connection refused" error message. I ssh'd into the server and tried to restart the daemon and got these errors. Thanks in advance! :)

```
[root@centos-desktop ~]# systemctl status vncserver@:1
● vncserver@:1.service - Remote desktop service (VNC)
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/vncserver@:1.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: resources) since Sun 2018-06-17 18:01:36 EDT; 1min 51s ago
  Process: 1324 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/runuser -l sam -c /usr/bin/vncserver %i -geometry 1366x768 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 1315 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c /usr/bin/vncserver -kill %i > /dev/null 2>&1 || : (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jun 17 18:01:33 centos-desktop.mylab.local systemd[1]: Starting Remote desktop service (VNC)...
Jun 17 18:01:36 centos-desktop.mylab.local systemd[1]: PID file /home/sam/.vnc/centos-desktop.mylab.local:1.pid not readable (yet?) after start.
Jun 17 18:01:36 centos-desktop.mylab.local systemd[1]: Failed to start Remote desktop service (VNC).
Jun 17 18:01:36 centos-desktop.mylab.local systemd[1]: Unit vncserver@:1.service entered failed state.
Jun 17 18:01:36 centos-desktop.mylab.local systemd[1]: vncserver@:1.service failed.
[root@centos-desktop ~]# systemctl start vncserver@:1
Job for vncserver@:1.service failed because a configured resource limit was exceeded. See "systemctl status vncserver@:1.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Comment: There's probably a `ulimit` to increase

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution here:

https://superuser.com/questions/806404/problems-configuring-the-vnc-session-for-rhel-7-on-power8#806750

```
vncserver -kill :1
```